# C : Memory Layout of c program and Endianess

Tags: c

I have one question regarding the Endianess and the memory Layout of a C Program.I tried searching couple of sites but couldn't get a satisfactory answer. "On the standard PC x86 computer architecture stack portion grows downwards to a lower memory area; on some other architectures it grows the opposite direction".

Does the stack grows reverse in Big Endian architecture. I guess the High Memory and Low Memory are logical Addresses and they are not the physical addresses.

is their a good reference material for the same.

Comment: The direction the stack grows is not related to the endianess of an architecture.

Answer (score 8):

Which way the stack grows has nothing to do with whether the machine is big- or little-endian.  All four combinations are possible, but the overwhelming majority of *both* big- and little-endian machines have a stack that grows from high to low addresses.

The direction the stack grows in is just a convention, although one that might be baked into the hardware to some extent.  New architectures tend to make the stack grow downward just because that's the most common convention and therefore some programs don't handle the other possibility correctly.  It was originally popular because it avoided having to decide how much space to allocate to the stack (this was on machines with less than 32K of RAM).

Logical vs physical addressing is yet another unrelated property.  Assuming by "logical" you mean "virtual", the stack grows -- whichever way it grows -- in the virtual address space if virtual memory is engaged, and in the physical address space if it isn't.  Some CPUs let you turn virtual memory off (e.g. x86), some don't (e.g. Alpha).

Comment: "Some CPUs let you turn virtual memory off" Technically they let the OS turn it on/off, no non-archaic OS (as far as I know) lets userland programs turn it off.

Comment: @kevin "You" was meant to refer to the person writing the operating system.

Comment: From the question I'd guess the OP isn't going to be writing an OS any time soon.

Comment: @kevin I dunno, this is exactly the sort of question I'd expect from someone fairly inexperienced who was trying to make sense of a CPU reference manual.

Comment: In addition to the stack growing either direction, it should be noted that the "stack frame" may grow either direction.  That is, the "frame header" may be on (or near) the low-address or high-address side of the storage representing the automatic variables in the frame.  Usually the frame header is on the low-address end, though often there is some storage (such as register save areas) "below" that.  It all can get incredibly involved, given that system designers will sell their first-born for 3 cycles saved in the call-return path.

Comment: Thanks everyone for clarifying the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered there is no relation between endianess and memory layout.
There is good info for memory layout of a program here.
http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/teoX.pdf

You can find all about endianess in wiki.
https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Endianness.html

Comment: thanks for sharing the . I guess that's the reason i was not getting the "satisfacotry answers". Now its clear